# Checking for missing files from web and download missing file

Tags: c#

How can I make a system in c # to check the list of required files from the  list.txt that is on the host and to add each file as separate to the code?

```
If (! File.Exists ("each file in the list"))
{
   WebClient client = new WebClient ();
   Client.DownloadFileAsync (new Uri (site + "missing file"), dir + "name of downloaded file");
}
```

Comment: Is that not working for you?

Comment: Your casing-usage is very "creative". How about posting a compiling code first?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to get a list from the file that is on the host

And that the other variable that retrieves the files knew which file from the list is missing

Comment: You keep saying “the file” and “the list” without showing us any files or lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var files = File.ReadAllLines("list.txt");
foreach (var filename in files)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(site + filename), dir + filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I draw a list directly from URL?